# How was the series derived(logarithms)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

[image]

[image]

I am revising and my past papers have short answers with no detail. My question is: How was the first series derived, and then why did they put the second series to be smaller than the first one(also how was it derived)?

Comment: What do you mean how was the first series derived?  The first series is what we want to prove is positive.  We can just write any series we want, then try to evaluate it.  If you are asking for the motivation for studying the first series, that should be in the book you are reading.  I can't guess.  Often it is a step in the proof of some theorem.

Comment: @RossMillikan well we have an 'm' on the first series. Where did it come from? and then how do we know sum(mp-1) is smaller than the first sum? Maybe there is a property or inequality which would make it clearer for me why the inequality..

Comment: The series in the answer are missing the limits, but are intended to run from $1$ to $m$ as the series in the question.  The multiplier $m$ is no problem as if we want to prove the original series is positive we can multiply it by a positive number $m$ and still have it positive.

Comment: @RossMillikan I get that the series run from 1 to m, but was confused from where the m came,since i thought it was extracted somewhere from within the expression in the sum.(like i thought they did not multiply it by m). Now I get what they did with the further inequality and everything is clear!.. Should I delete the question?

Comment: The important thing is to think about what you are asking.  They could have put some words like "we will multiply the series by $m$ to show it is positive" or something like that to give the motivation for using this series.  That is a clever idea worth $40\%$ of the credit because you get the form $x\log x$, which we know things about.  The question should have been "why did they choose to study the series multiplied by $m$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $h(x)=x\log(x)$ with $h(0)=0$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and smooth on $(0,\infty)$. Its first two derivatives are
$$
h'(x)=\log(x)+1\\
h''(x)=\frac1x
$$
so that the function is convex and monotonically increasing for $x>e^{-1}$.

Use the convexity and the supporting line/tangent at $x=1$ to conclude that
$$
h(x)\ge h(1)+h'(1)(x-1)=x-1.\tag1
$$

---

To get the claimed inequality into a form that you can apply this above inequality (1), you need to multiply it by $m$ so that
$$
m\sum_{i=1}^mp_i\log(mp_i)=\sum_{i=1}^m h(mp_i)\ge\sum_{i=1}^m(mp_i-1)=0
$$

---

In total this shows that the entropy is bounded,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m(-p_i\log(p_i))\le\log(m)
$$